# How does sentences and text are represented in NLP?

Tags: nlp

Sentences are just sequences of words. These sequences can have a lot of ambiguities. One of the main goals of natural languages processing is to represent sentences as something that has more structure and less ambiguities.

So, my question is: What are the ways to represent sentences? I assume that there are many alternative approaches to that. What are the difference between them? Do they have their advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: Possibly (up till now), Languages can be computationally structured as: strings, ngrams, trees, graph, vectors.

Comment: @alvas, I do not think that string is a structure that represent a sentence structure well. Inherently sentence is more than a sequence. Graphs, I believe, is a better representation, but how exactly it works. How the nodes are defined, how the edges are defined?

Comment: For graphs, read up on https://www.google.com/search?q=graph+nlp  . String is a "seriously" overused structure in NLP. most neural nets depends on strings (without lemmas/concepts). most machine translations depends on strings too (a chain of strings = ngrams). There's much on can get from strings.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question, but probably a sufficient answer is: discrete v.s. continuous representations are two different paradigms. Discrete version is where words are represented by indexes corresponding to i.e. their position in a dictionary. This leads to having a vector representation for each sentence where the vector (dimension: |vocabulary|) is very sparse and has 1s for its words and zero elsewhere.

Another paradigm is to replace the vector representation of discrete values with a vector of continuos real values learned via neural network. This started from LSA, and was the general idea behind word2vec, and the basis for many great works over the past 2-3 years in the nlp community.

Comment: But in what you call "discrete representation" the structure of the sentence is lost. In your huge vector containing only 1 and 0 you just indicate what words are present in the sentence end even the order of the words is lost. So, I wanted to know how to switch from a sequence to something richer and what you propose is opposite to that. We loose information and switch from sequence to something that is less informative.

Comment: The second part of your answer is more about words representation. Yes, words can be represented as numerical vectors. My questions is, however, about sentence representation. Sentence is more than a sequence of set of words. I believe that words in sentence are structured as a tree or a graph.

Comment: I am not proposing anything :). Just explained how it is represented in the field. To answer your question: there is no "single" and rich representation of text that can handle all the tasks. You need to combine information from different sources: surface which is based on words, syntactic (syntaxt trees), and semantic (sentiments, etc) levels. What you combine and how you combine them depends on the task you are aiming to do and they typically happen in the modeling and/or prediction phase(s) of whatever system you are developing.

Comment: And regarding the second comment you left: I haven't seen any method that represents words as tree, or graph. However, if you are interested in the grammatical structure of "sentences", you will see parse trees very often.